# Remove whitespaces from logback message if a variable value is empty

Tags: logback

I use the following logback pattern:

```
<pattern>%X{version} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %.-1level %C{0}:%M:%L %msg %n</pattern>
```

This produces a nice output if `version` is set but there are valid cases when it can be empty.

In this case, there is a leading whitespace in every logline (resulting from the space between `%X{version}` and `%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}`).

The simple solution is to remove the whitespace from the pattern and append it to the value of version. Is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the omitEmptyFields option.

Example:

```
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                      "myField": {
                        "mySubField": "%mdc{abc}"
                      },
                      "myField2": "%mdc{abc}" 
                    }
                </pattern>
                <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
            </pattern>
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder#event-specific-custom-fields
- https://elvisciotti.medium.com/logback-non-access-spring-logs-with-custom-json-format-and-mdc-1c6f1fbf28c4